# Weird Unity error after moving editors to external SSD

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been working on unity on a windows laptop, and recently ran out of storage space.  I copied and deleted the editors (besides 2021.3) to my ssd to free up disk space, then re-located them with the unity hub.  However, when I try to open a project I get this error:

[image]

and after force quitting, this message:

[image]

Is there any way to salvage this, and if not, can I reinstall unity and find my saved projects again?  Thanks, I do not want to lose all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what was up, but I got my stuff to open after about 10 minutes.  Maybe the transfer was just sort of hidden in the background for a bit.  Huh.

Comment: Good case for regular backups :) Just zip the Assets and Project Settings folders and then you can always rebuild your project from the zip.